# Linear Algebra Don't Understand a question involving basis

Tags: linear-algebra

the question is

Find $[t^2-3t+4]_B$

I am given a basis $B=\{4,1+t,1-t^2\}$

Could someone explain how to attempt this problem and what exactly am I supposed to do? I am not asking for the answer.

Comment: Presumably you are supposed to write the function in terms of a combination of basis elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\renewcommand{\vec}{\bar}$
You want to find the numbers $c_1,\ c_2,\ c_3$ such that
$$t^2-3t+4=c_1\cdot4+c_2\cdot(1+t)+c_3\cdot(1-t^2),$$
just like you normally look for $\vec u=c_1\vec v_1+c_2\vec v_2+c_3\vec v_3$. A hint is that you can see the polynomial $t^2-3t+4$ as the vector $\Big(\!\begin{smallmatrix}4\\-3\\1\end{smallmatrix}\!\Big)$, and similar with the other ones.

Comment: i got a=2 b=-3 and c=-1

Comment: i made a matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 1 & 1 & 4\\
0 & 1 & 0 & -3\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}\\$

Comment: That is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

You are being asked to express the polynomial $t^2-3t+4$ in terms of the basis $B=\{4,1+t,1-t^2\}$; in other words, you want to find numbers $a,b,c$ such that 
$$a\cdot 4 + b\cdot(1+t)+c\cdot(1-t^2) = t^2-3t+4.$$

Comment: How would I do this, is it similar to solving linear combinations without variables such as making a matrix?